# Display exclamation marks (!) in command-line script with EnableDelayedExpansion

Tags: windows, batch-file

The output of this batch script is `Hello!` as expected:

```
@echo off
echo Hello!
```

However, with Delayed Expansion enabled the output is now `Hello`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Hello!
```

A trick is to insert `endlocal` just before the `echo`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...
endlocal
echo Hello!
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

This is tedious, however. According to [this Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo), some charaters like percent (%) and caret (^) can be used to escape (and therefore print) characters such as `%`, `|` and `>`.

Is there any escape character for the exclamation mark (!) without resorting to the `endlocal` trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with double caret:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

echo ^^!
```

Comment: Either two or three carets should do it, _although why use three when two will do!_

Answer (score 0):

one can take @npocmaka's answer a step further, so that exclamation marks can be dispalyed without expanding in later use.

```
@Echo Off & setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "/Ex=^^!"

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo(%/Ex%test%/Ex%
```

[image]

Comment: Is that not still expanding `/Ex` into `^^!` which displays `!`? Command-line scripting is powerful, but its pretty weird... :o)

Comment: in effect, yes, I suggest this approach primarily for purposes of readability and maintenance.

Comment: wait until you discover the tricks that can be achived with for loops to manipulate variables, or the super wierd behavior of Call echo / Call Set